# Round a column in Python

Tags: python, pandas, decimal, rounding, zero

I would like to round one specific column to 1 decimal place. Currently I am using the following code:

> `scatterLabelsEinkommen['Einkommen'].round(decimals=2)`

I get the following error:

loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type float which has no callable rint method

Do you know how to overcome this error?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: what type are the entries in your dictionary?

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You could try `scatterLabelsEinkommen['Einkommen'] = round(scatterLabelsEinkommen['Einkommen'], 1)`

Comment: the entries are int64. Your suggested code also produced the same error.

Comment: Da kann ich dann auch nicht mehr helfen digga

Comment: Es hat leere Zellen gehabt. Diese habe ich mit 0 ersetzt. Nun funktioniert es. Viele Dank!

Comment: achso, also war das problem das manche zellen einfach `''` waren?

Comment: das ist richtig.